# actionPerformed triggered when expanding window

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, actionlistener

I am trying to gain a better understanding of GUI programming in Java and some strange behavior has occurred. The program shows a circle with a gradient of random colors, and when you click the button the colors change. Very simple, except that I noticed when I accidentally expanded the window, the actionPerformed was triggered, and the button would constantly change colors as if I were spamming the button. My question is why this happened? I am using a Windows environment, if that matters. My code:

```
public class SimpleGui3C implements ActionListener {
JFrame frame;

public static void main (String[] args) {
    SimpleGui3C gui = new SimpleGui3C();
    gui.go();
}

public void go() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JButton button = new JButton("Change Colors");
    button.addActionListener(this);

    MyDrawPanel drawPanel = new MyDrawPanel();

    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, button);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, drawPanel);
    frame.setSize(300, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    frame.repaint();
}

}
```

---

MyDrawPanel

```
class MyDrawPanel extends JPanel {

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

    int red = (int) (Math.random() * 256);
    int green = (int) (Math.random() * 256);
    int blue = (int) (Math.random() * 256);
    Color startColor = new Color(red, green, blue);

    red = (int) (Math.random() * 256);
    green = (int) (Math.random() * 256);
    blue = (int) (Math.random() * 256);
    Color endColor = new Color(red, green, blue);

    GradientPaint gradient = new GradientPaint(70,70,startColor, 150,150, endColor);
    g2d.setPaint(gradient);
    g2d.fillOval(70,70,100,100);
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, actionPerformed is most definitely **not** being triggered. Rather a `repaint()` is being triggered.  Your problem is that you're randomizing within the paintComponent method, and you should never change the state of the class from this method since you do not have full control over when or even **if** it should or can be called.

Instead do your randomization within the actionPerformed method, set red, blue, and green instance fields, call repaint, and use those fields within the paintComponent method.

Something like:

```
private int red1, green1, blue1, red2, green2, blue2;

@Override
public void actionPerfomed(ActionEvent e) {
    red1 = (int) (Math.random() * 256);
    green1 = (int) (Math.random() * 256);
    blue1 = (int) (Math.random() * 256);

    red2 = (int) (Math.random() * 256);
    green2 = (int) (Math.random() * 256);
    blue2 = (int) (Math.random() * 256);
    repaint();
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

    Color startColor = new Color(red1, green1, blue1);
    Color endColor = new Color(red2, green2, blue2);

    GradientPaint gradient = new GradientPaint(70,70,startColor, 150,150, endColor);
    g2d.setPaint(gradient);
    g2d.fillOval(70,70,100,100);
}
```

e.g.,

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GradientPaint;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SimpleGui3C {

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        final MyDrawPanel gui = new MyDrawPanel();

        JButton drawButton = new JButton(new AbstractAction("Randomize") {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                gui.randomizeColor();
            }
        });

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SimpleGui3C");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(gui);
        frame.getContentPane().add(drawButton, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class MyDrawPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final int PREF_W = 800;
    private static final int PREF_H = 650;
    private static final int OVAL_X = 70;
    private static final int OVAL_W = 100;
    private int red1, green1, blue1, red2, green2, blue2;

    public MyDrawPanel() {
        int w = OVAL_W + 2 * OVAL_X;
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(w, w));
        randomizeColor();
    }

    public void randomizeColor() {
        red1 = (int) (Math.random() * 256);
        green1 = (int) (Math.random() * 256);
        blue1 = (int) (Math.random() * 256);

        red2 = (int) (Math.random() * 256);
        green2 = (int) (Math.random() * 256);
        blue2 = (int) (Math.random() * 256);
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g); // ***** Don't forget this *****
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        Color startColor = new Color(red1, green1, blue1);
        Color endColor = new Color(red2, green2, blue2);

        GradientPaint gradient = new GradientPaint(70, 70, startColor, 150, 150, endColor);
        g2d.setPaint(gradient);
        g2d.fillOval(OVAL_X, OVAL_X, OVAL_W, OVAL_W);
    }
}
```

Also, don't forget to call the `super.paintComponent(g);` in your override (see code above)

Comment: That makes so much more sense, thank you. I wasn't completely sure how the repaint method worked.

Comment: @Ebotchl: it suggests to the paint manager to start the painting chain, but again so does a re-size. Please see example code above. Also don't forget to call the super's paintComponent method to clean up the graphics, and use rendering hints to smooth out your edges.

Comment: *"I wasn't completely sure how the repaint method worked."* Doing some basic debugging, or putting a `println` in the action performed method would have helped that understanding..